# parse string to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, domparser

I have the following string :

```
var str = ‘<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />’
```

How can I to transform this to DOM.
I have tried with DOMParser something like this.

```
var parser = new DOMParser()
var el = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
console.log(el)
```

But, getting error. This is the output.

```
#document
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js">
     <parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black">
        <h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3>
        <div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 27: Extra content at the end of the document
        </div>
        <h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3>
    </parsererror>
</script>
```

As showing the output, the css has not been parsed too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `DOMParser` can only parse a single element.

So this works:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString("<div/>", "text/xml")
```

but this doesn't:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString("<div/><div/>", "text/xml")
```

So you could probably fix your example by putting a tag around the whole thing.

Comment: XML documents can only contain a single document element node. The result is a document object so it can only contain one root element node. The second one is `Extra content at the end of the document`.

Answer (score 0):

Your single quotes are wrong? Please double check.

I think you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) to transfer easily:

```
var s = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />';
var v = $(s);
```